# How can transfer files between RPI and Windows PC via Bluetooth_OBEX?

Tags: python, bluetooth, file-sharing, file-server, sockets

I try to build computer program that trasfer files use Bluetooth and OBEX technology between **Windows and RPI**. I use BLuetooth  RFCOMM Server @ Windows Side. RPI is @ client side. I use **pybluez and PyObex** for both side. 
Now I sent file from RPI side. However I can't catch  the file @ Windows side. Code elements figured at below.

### Server Side:

```
class BlueDev(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.socket = BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
        self.server = BrowserServer()
        self.port = None
    def startService(self):
        """ Starts Socket and Advertising Service """

        self.socket.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
        self.port = self.socket.getsocketname()[1]
        self.socket.listen(1)
        self.server.start_service(self.socket) ## advertise server
        self.server.serve(self.socket) ## accepts connection
if __name__ == "__main__"
    blueDevServ = BlueDev()
    blueDevServ.startService()
```

### Client Side:

```
class BluetoothDev(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = None
        self.socket = Bluetooth(RFCOMM)
        self.port = None
        self.address = ""
    def startService(self):
        if sys.version < '3':
            input = raw_input
        if len(sys.argv) < 2:
            print("No device")
        services = bluetooth.find_service(uuid=OBEX_FILETRANS_CLASS, address=self.address)
        servicesMatch = services[0]
        port = servicesMatch["port"] 
        self.address = servicesMatch["host"]
        print(port , self.address)
        self.client = client.BrowserClient(self.address,port)
        print("Client is ready")
    def connect(self):
        self.client.connect()
        print "Connected from client Side"
if __name__ == "__main__":

    blueClient = BluetoothDev()
    devices = blueClient.discover()
    blueClient.startService()
    print("Waiting for server service")
    blueClient.connect()
    client.put('test.txt', 'HelloWorld!')
    print("File Sent:")
```

I couldn't find missing elements on architecture.How can i catch sent files on Server Side?

Comment: I solved file transfer process without OBEX. I used basic socket to data transfer. After accept connection @ServerSide:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem without OBEX. I used socket's recv() and send(). After accept connection @ServerSide

```
def sendFile(self ,sendPath,packageSize):
    """
    Sends file to the device
    @param sendPath is file path address @ host device
    @param packageSize is packet size of pure data @BluetoothSocket
    """
    if (packageSize == None):
        packageSize = 1024
    f = open(sendPath,'rb')
    self.clientSocket.send(sendPath)##send EXACT name of file 
    packet = 1
    print(sendPath ,"is", os.pat.getsize(sendPath), "starts @", time.ctime())
    while (packet):
        packet = f.read(1024)
        self.clientSocket.send(packet)
    print("Send @:", time.ctime())
    isFileSent = True
    f.close()
```

@ClientSide after accept() from server side:

```
def getFile(self, gotPath, packageSize):
    """
    Collects arriving packets
    """
    if (packageSize == None):
        packageSize = 1024
    name = self.socket.recv(packageSize)
    f = open(name, wb)
    packet = 1
    while packet:
        packet = self.socket.recv(packageSize)
        f.write(packet)
    self.isFileGot= True
    f.close()
    print ("File GOT")
```